# Bluetooth Low Energy beacons distance with Python

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluez, rssi

I've been tasked with calculating the distance between a Raspberry Pi and a couple of Bluetooth Low Energy beacons (using Bluetooth of course).

This seems to be a relatively common idea, but so far all the answers I've found have been either incomplete or are unsuitable, usually because there are different rules governing Bluetooth Low Energy devices and setups that include, say, linking two phones together.

My code looks something like this example, albeit with a few minor changes:

https://github.com/tholum/bluez/blob/master/blue.py

That is to say I can pick up a beacon's MAC address, UUID, major and minor numbers and a value for "TX Power", however I apparently need another value - the current RSSI, recorded by the Raspberry Pi which is meant to describe how strong the signal is.

I can get the RSSI thorough the terminal (so I know it's supported), using

```
sudo btmon & hcitool lescan
```

But I want to obtain it through Python, so I can do some calculations and work out a distance in metres (I'm aware interference can screw with those readings but I can deal with that).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To get RSSI I'm using [bluepy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) module which shows the RSSI:

```
    Device c2:d9:46:fa:67:82 (random), RSSI=-67 dB
      Flags = 04
      Tx Power = fa
      16b Service Data = 0a180804951e0000
      Incomplete 128b Services = ba5689a6fabfa2bd01467d6e00fbabad
```